# How to make this Adapter searchable?

Tags: android, object, search, arraylist, searchview

**This is the Adapter for my List view..**
i want to **add a Filter or search feature into it**. please help me.
But i have seen many codes but none has helped me implement it. and i have not seen a adapter which extends ArrayAdapter which has a getFilter in it. so please help me.

```
public class FullNameAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Name> implements Filterable {

    public FullNameAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Name> words){
        super(context, 0, words);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        View listItemView = convertView;
        if(listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.main_listview, parent, false);
        }
        Name currentWord = getItem(position);

        TextView mainNumber = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.mainNumber_page);
        mainNumber.setText(currentWord.getMainNumber());

        TextView sanskritName = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.sanskrit_name_text_view_ml);
        sanskritName.setText(currentWord.getSanskritName());

        TextView scientificName = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.scientific_name_text_view_ml);
        scientificName.setText(currentWord.getScientificName());

        TextView familyName = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.family_text_view_ml);
        familyName.setText(currentWord.getFamilyName());

        ShapeableImageView panel_IMG_back = (ShapeableImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.mainList_imageView);
        Glide.with(getContext()).load(currentWord.getPicId()).into(panel_IMG_back);
        panel_IMG_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Dialog builder = new Dialog(getContext());
                builder.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                builder.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
                        new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

                builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                        //nothing;
                    }
                });

                ZoomageView imageView = new ZoomageView(getContext());
                imageView.setImageResource(currentWord.getPicId());
                builder.addContentView(imageView, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

                builder.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
                builder.show();

            }
        });return listItemView;}}
```

Please Help!

In MAIN ACTIVITY,  the Action Bar SEARCH VIEW in the Main activity, what should do? here

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.list_menu, menu);
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                
                return true;
            }
        });
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

These are the Objects that i added to my array list, i want to search in some of them and if the string in the array is matching then the array list can be shown in the list. but if the Name doesnt have a matching string it should go!

```
private void smallaaray() {
        array = new ArrayList<Name>();
        array.add(new Name("1", "akhil","", "", R.drawable.0,
                R.string.0, "",
                "","","","","","","","","","","","","",R.drawable.0,R.drawable.0,R.drawable.0,R.drawable.0));
```

Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found A Simple & Complex Solution.

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setQueryHint("Search All Data!");
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener (new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String q) {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            if (BUYED_APP == false){
                Toast.makeText(NonDetailDrugActivity.this, "Your are Searching on a Short list of 10 Drugs Only.\nPlease Subscribe to Gain Access to Full Data!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            filter = new ArrayList<>();
            filter.clear();
            if (s.length() == 0) {
                filter.addAll(array);
            } else {
                for (Name post : array) {
                    String filterPattern = s.toLowerCase().trim();
                    if (post.getSanskritName().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                        filter.add(post);
                    } else {
                        filter.retainAll(array);
                        if (post.getScientificName().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                            filter.add(post);
                        } else {
                            filter.retainAll(array);
                            if (post.getFamilyName().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                                filter.add(post);
                            } else {
                                filter.retainAll(array);
                                if (post.getOtherName().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                                    filter.add(post);
                                }else {
                                    filter.retainAll(array);
                                    if (post.getAmayikaPrayogam().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                                        filter.add(post);
                                    }else {
                                        filter.retainAll(array);
                                        if (post.getYogas().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                                            filter.add(post);
                                        }else {
                                            filter.retainAll(array);
                                            if (post.getKarma().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                                                filter.add(post);
                                            } else {
                                                filter.retainAll(array);
                                                if (post.getMalayalamNameId().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                                                    filter.add(post);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            adap.clear();
            adap.addAll(filter);
            adap.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
        }
    });
    searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClose() {
            clearSearch();
            searchView.onActionViewCollapsed();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

&

```
private void clearSearch(){
adap.clear();
filter.clear();
smallaaray();
adap.addAll(array);
adap.notifyDataSetChanged(); }
```

That way! I made my Search possible.! Thank you SO much for the Help Everyone.

Answer (score 0):

The adapter only cares about data and views. Filtering and searching should be operations on the data source. Therefore, you should update the adapter after operating on the data source

Comment: I have added it as a arraylist into the NameAdapter. u Mean i have to modify something in the Name Java Class?

Comment: yes,modify arraylist and call "adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()"

Comment: can u please help me with coding that... im getting error always... please help bro..

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom filter like below,
& pass your list to setFilterList() method of adapter for searching/filtering

To trigger searching:

**adapter.getFilter().filter(<search_char>);**

```
public class FullNameAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Name> implements Filterable {

    public FullNameAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Name> words) {
        super(context, 0, words);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        View listItemView = convertView;
        if (listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_bonus, parent, false);
        }
        Name currentWord = getItem(position);

        return listItemView;
    }

    CustomFilter filter;

    public void setFilterList(List<Name> filterList) {
        this.filterList = filterList;
    }

    List<Name> filterList;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CustomFilter getFilter() {
        return filter;
    }

    public class CustomFilter extends Filter {
        ArrayList<Name> filterList;

        public CustomFilter(ArrayList<Name> filterList) {
            this.filterList = filterList;
        }

        //FILTERING OCCURS
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            //CHECK CONSTRAINT VALIDITY
            if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
                //CHANGE TO UPPER
                constraint = constraint.toString().toUpperCase();
                //STORE OUR FILTERED PLAYERS
                ArrayList<Name> filteredPlayers = new ArrayList<>();
                if (filterList != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < filterList.size(); i++) {
                        //CHECK
                        try {
                            if (filterList.get(i).getNameName().toUpperCase().contains(constraint)) {
                                //ADD PLAYER TO FILTERED PLAYERS
                                filteredPlayers.add(filterList.get(i));
                            }
                        } catch (Throwable e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                results.count = filteredPlayers.size();
                results.values = filteredPlayers;
            } else {
                results.count = filterList.size();
                results.values = filterList;
            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            clear();
            if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                add((Name) results.values);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But it crashed when i started typing the character in the search view. I added it to the
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }
        
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                adap.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return true;
            }

Comment: Thank u for this much information..  But The NAME object contains Many Strings, Resource Id etc. i need the New filterPlayers to have all that as well. but here its only the one thing is being added to the filteredPlayer. please help.

Comment: there is the comparison code in the performFiltering() method of filter where you have to compare your search string with the your object's any of the field like Name, title etc.

Comment: How to do that! can u give a example. it will be a great help

And the setFilterList method, what should i do with it

Comment: Please help me with solving this issue. You r my last hope.

Comment: pass your original list to setFilterList() method

Comment: ya... i tried that too! but still the app is crashing..
and this is the error
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.gokulrajendran.FullNameAdapter$CustomFilter.filter(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.gokulrajendran.FullDetailActivity$3.onQueryTextChange

Comment: please help i tried it and then also the result is same.. please help